# Caching Large File in Java

Tags: java, caching

I have a large binary file (300KB), which I am storing as a medium blob in a database table. The file content changes once a day. There are multiple clients requesting various byte-ranges from the file. Instead of making a database call for each request, I want to cache the entire file for a day. We have a distributed system. We use Tomcat, MySQL and the language is Java. What is the best way to cache the file?

Comment: for a single file?  put it in a file on disk and have a background task which periodically updates it.

Comment: 300kb isn't large... put it in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put an HTTP proxy like Squid in front of your application server or in front of your web server if you have one.  Squid may be configured to cache the content of the response.  Strategy for the caching can be controlled with HTTP header fields.  This is a nice solution that does not require development and works well for large files since your application server is not involved when a cached document is accessed.
Another solution is to use ehcache (or another cache but ehcache is the one I have experience with).  You could configure it to cache the document when it is returned by the service that you implemented for that purpose.
In your context the gain is lower than with a HTTP proxy since your application server is involved when cached document is accessed.  But the database is not.  This solution bring a more significant gain when accessing the resource requires long time processing.
Note that ehcache is easily integrated with Spring-cache.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a web application. If that's the case, you can store the data as attribute in `ServletContext`. Then, every time you receive a request, read from this attribute rather than accessing to database every time. Also, you can establish a task to update this attribute every day automatically at a given time or on demand.

If your application is not a web application or you want/need a more generic solution, use a cache library like EhCache or Infinispan which support caching cross JVMs. You may consider using Hazelcast as well.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a singleton as describe here: http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html.

The singleton will store this binary and refresh it when customer request it and the reference is more than 1 day old.

Here's the pseudocode.

```
class SingletonBlob{

private static Binary myFile;
private static Date lastUpdate;

public static getMyFile(){
 if(myFile == null or lastUpdate > 1 day){
   myFile = fetchFromMysql();
 }
 return myFile;
}
```

Comment: This is a big no. You should avoid using singletons.

Comment: If performances is your concern, you can use Thread-safe implementation with a dual locking mechanism. As argued in the link I provided.

Comment: Still is a big no. There are technologies that helps you to not use this approach **at all**.